# 'Premature EOF while reading JPG.' exception in iTextSharp with .NET Core 6 C#

Tags: c#, itext, asp.net-core-6.0

I generate pdf for my pdf report. This works fine.
But I don't why for 1 record this is giving exception.

```
'Premature EOF while reading JPG.'
```

Below is my code

```
Image imgIdProof = Image.GetInstance(employee.IdentityProofURL);
                    imgIdProof.ScaleAbsolute(250f, 250f);
```

I pass URL to Image.GetInstance(), then exception occured.

Image URL is-

```
https://eaddressblob.blob.core.windows.net/eaddresscontainer/2328508ad4f7491f86b213dad906aeca.jpg?sv=2021-04-10&se=2022-05-02T10%3A42%3A13Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=b9yw3vowDmxqwhlfXUBZjOYW64%2FzmFpt4usVzUc4aHY%3D
```

If I paste this url in browser, this works fine and shows the image.
But throwing exception with code.

Any help on this please?

I want to solve this by code only. Not manually.So this kind of exception should be handled automatically in future.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to retrieve the image results in

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:f7d5c989-301e-002e-2839-5ea291000000 Time:2022-05-02T15:27:05.9888340Z</Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signed expiry time [Mon, 02 May 2022 10:42:13 GMT] must be after signed start time [Mon, 02 May 2022 15:27:05 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Maybe when you *paste this url in browser*, your browser adds some authorization header from an earlier visit to that page or some domain login. iText doesn't have that authorization information and, therefore, cannot send that header.